# Pass applescript variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, applescript, osx-yosemite

I cannot get an applescript variable to be recognized within a do Javascript block.
Previous versions of Script Editor seem to recognize the variable, but not Yosemite.

```
set myVar to 123
tell application "Safari" 
do Javascript " document.getElementById('filter1FieldValueId').value= dsid ;" in front document  
end tell
```

This is one of the various tasks I need to accomplish, and if anyone can suggest how to give JavaScript a variable outside of the DO JAVASCRIPT, that would be so helpful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string together into a valid JavaScript string using the concatenate `&` operator. AppleScript will not interpret variables in a string.

```
set myVar to 123
tell application "Safari" 
    do Javascript " document.getElementById('filter1FieldValueId').value= " & myVar & " ;" in front document  
end tell
```